# Remove "nofollow" from widget_text

Tags: nofollow

How can I remove rel "nofollow" from a widget_text?
I'd like to try a solution without install a plugin.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though a plugin or theme function is already adding 'nofollow' to the widget, so it might be a case of needing to remove a plugin not add one.

It might be being added in your Theme's functions file with the following function: [wp_rel_nofollow](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_rel_nofollow/)

You could try searching for that function thought your plugins and themes.

Comment: I resolved. It was a problem of setting Platinum SEO plugin.

Comment: Ok great, so it was another plugin. Please accept my answer so we both get some reputation points :)